# Gypsum and ........... Equals drywall mud?

Tags: repair, drywall, spackling-paste

What can I add to gypsum to make drywall "mud"? I have a whole bag of gypsum for my garden, is that the same type to make "mud"? Also, is tape need to use mud? And what is the dry time on something like that? I'm looking to fix various nail holes before painting and this atrosity .[image]

Comment: Garden gypsum cannot be made into drywall mud. Save it for your garden or give it away.

Comment: how does the picture relate to the question about gypsum?

Comment: Jsotola, that is one of the holes in my wall left after baseboards were ripped out. I am trying to fix that as well as various nail holes before painting.

Answer (score 5):

The compound is a complex combination often including water, limestone, expanded perlite, ethylene-vinyl acetate polymer, attapulgite, and other ingredients, this was from online ,  but it answers the question of what's it made of.